# How to correctrly assign function to prop of setState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, render

I want to change form submit handler which depends on my activities: adding data(this._handleFormSubmit) or updating data(this._handleFormUpdateSubmit)
I have following constructor of react component which takes initial submit handler for adding data:

```
this.state = {
        modalSubmitHandler:this._handleFormSubmit}
```

_handleFormUpdateSubmit:

```
_handleFormUpdateSubmit(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    CocAccountsActions.editAccount(this.state.modalData);
}
```

_handleFormSubmit:

```
_handleFormSubmit(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    AccountsActions.addAccount(this.state.modalData);
}
```

When i click on some button on the container. form submit handler is changing from adding data to updating data:

```
_handleUpdateAccount(id)
{         
    this.setState({
        modalSubmitHandler:this._handleFormUpdateSubmit,
    });
}
```

Resultant form handler outputs here:

```
render(){
return(
<div>
<form  onSubmit={(e)=>this.state.modalSubmitHandler(e)}>
        ...
```

Problem is when i click on some form elements which have themselves handlers(images clearing...), i make component rerender and form onSubmit calls update data handler(_handleFormUpdateSubmit). How to avoid calling onSubmit function after rerendering?

Comment: Why are you putting `this._handleFormSubmit` in state?

Comment: to switch between handlers for a form

Comment: Right, but couldn't you store e.g. a boolean in your state instead and check agains that for what type of submit handler you should use? Could you include your entire component in the question? It's hard to see what might be wrong from the current code.